# Legend type when plotting different geometries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following datatable:

```
> example_dt <-data.table(x = c(0,0.41,0.85,0.92,0.78, 0, 0.35, 0.38, 0.47, 0.6), y = c(2322, 2446, 2524, 2563, 2602, 2322, 3718, 3729, 3747, 3777), type = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'))
> example_dt
       x    y type
 1: 0.00 2322    A
 2: 0.41 2446    A
 3: 0.85 2524    A
 4: 0.92 2563    A
 5: 0.78 2602    A
 6: 0.00 2322    B
 7: 0.35 3718    B
 8: 0.38 3729    B
 9: 0.47 3747    B
10: 0.60 3777    B
```

I plot:

```
> example_dt %>% ggplot(aes(color = type)) +
+     geom_point(data = example_dt[type == 'A',], aes(x = x, y = y)) +
+     geom_line(data = example_dt[type == 'B',], aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
+     scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse")
```

[image: plot]

As you can see, the legend shows as if both geoms were lines. How can I show, in the legend, the appropriate point format for type A?

Comment: sorry, just did it.

Comment: use `guides(...)`. Also, you've got a lot of repetition. You just need `ggplot(aes(x, y, col=type)` and the other geoms can omit them.